# Finding a specific "route" through a network simulator

Tags: python, networking, simulation, simulator

I'm writing something for a game that involves networks. In this game, a network is a class and the "connections" to each node are formatted like:

```
network.nodes = [router, computer1, computer2]
network.connections = [ [1, 2], [0], [0] ]
```

Each iteration in "network.nodes" works in parallel with each iteration in "network.connections", meaning "network.connections[0]" represents all the nodes "network.nodes[0]" is connected to. I'm trying to write a simple function in the network class that finds a route starting from the router - "network.connections[0]" - and then to a specific "node". The more thought I put into this, the more complicated the answer seems to be.

In this, rather simple case it should return something like

```
[router, computer1]
```

That's what I'd like to see if I was trying to find a route to "computer1", but I need something that will work with more complicated network simulations.

It's basically a simulator for a computer network. But in this game, I need to be able to know exactly which nodes something might travel though to reach a specific target.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about dropping the `.nodes` and `.connections` and just keeping them in one data structure like a dictionary.

```
network.nodes = {"router": [computer1, computer2],
                 "computer1": [router],
                 "computer2": [router]
                 }
```

You could even drop the strings as keys and use the objects themselves:

```
network.nodes = {router: [computer1, computer2],
                 computer1: [router],
                 computer2: [router]
                 }
```

That way if you need to access the the connections for the router you would do:

```
>>>network.nodes[router]
[computer1, computer2]
```

Because I don't have a full overview of your project, I can't just give you a function to do that, but I can try and point you in the right direction.

If you build the network 'map' up as a dictionary, and `network.nodes[router]` returns `[computer1, computer2]`, the next thing you would need to do is `network.nodes[computer1]` and `network.nodes[computer2]`.

In your firewall example from the comments, you would rebuild the network map to include the firewall. So the dictionary would look like this:

```
network.nodes = {router: [firewall, computer2],
                firewall: [computer1]
                computer1: [firewall],
                computer2: [router]
                }
```

Comment: Actually, this could help. But doesn't quite solve the problem. I'll probably take your advice, but I still need a function that returns every route that something would need to take to get to a specific node.

Comment: For example, if there was a firewall in between the router and "computer1" so the router and "computer1" weren't connected directly, I'd need a program that would go through every node and return something like
[router, firewall, computer1]

Comment: Actually I may have just figured it out. Not exactly the answer I wanted, but I know how to fix it with your advice so it works. The reason I came here for help was because the connections could have gone on forever based on the way I was setting it up. So I needed a function that could run through every possible route and return the exactly one I needed.

But using your method I could just limit the amount of hops a node can be from the router. Thanks. I appreciate it.